# How to make the sum of specific elements from a list?

Tags: java

I want to make the sum of specific elements from an ArrayList. The elements are extracted from my sql db.

Here is what I tried by now but the result is not what I want.

Code:

```
ArrayList<Ehealth> datalist = new ArrayList<Ehealth>();

while(rs.next()) {

    Integer grasimi = rs.getInt("Total_grasimi");
    Integer carbohidrati = rs.getInt("Total_carbohidrati");                   
    Integer proteine = rs.getInt("Total_proteine");
    Integer calorii = rs.getInt("Total_calorii");

    Ehealth ehealthlist =
         new Ehealth(grasimi,carbohidrati,proteine,calorii);

    datalist.add(ehealthlist);

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(ehealthlist.calorii);
    int sum = 0;

    for (Integer integer : numbers) {
        sum = sum + integer;
    }

    System.out.println(sum);         
}
```

My result in console are the values extracted from db of the specific category
eg:

```
364
586
586
183
586
449
458
```

I want to make the sum of these numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: what is going wrong ? Ehealth(,grasimi,carbohidrati,proteine,calorii);

Comment: This can't be your real code since `new Ehealth(,grasimi,carbohidrati,proteine,calorii);` would not compile. Please pay more attention to details.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? You are printing, resetting the numbers list and setting sum variable back to 0 inside the while loop...  Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is in  `int sum = 0;` line, becouse in every `while` loop you are setting `sum` to 0. Please try it:

```
ArrayList<Ehealth> datalist = new ArrayList<Ehealth> ();

int sum = 0;

while(rs.next()){
    Integer grasimi = rs.getInt("Total_grasimi");
    Integer carbohidrati = rs.getInt("Total_carbohidrati");
    Integer proteine = rs.getInt("Total_proteine");
    Integer calorii = rs.getInt("Total_calorii");

    Ehealth ehealthlist = new Ehealth(grasimi,carbohidrati,proteine,calorii);

    datalist.add(ehealthlist);
}

for (Ehealth ehealth : datalist) {
    sum += ehealth.calorii;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: is it works >  Ehealth ehealthlist = new Ehealth(,grasimi,carbohidrati,proteine,calorii);

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answers rather than "try it"

Comment: It worked.But it returns me the sum of the last operation.Ex:364+586 = 950 then 950+586=1536,etc.I want the last sum.Sorry for my extra ","but the structure is longer I deleted what is not important.

Comment: I think another problem is the creation of an unnecessary integer arraylist within the loop

Comment: @Bogdan if my answer solved your problem pls mark it as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should get all your data from the database, and then do what you want with that list at a later point.

For example

```
// Get all records 
ArrayList<Ehealth> datalist = new ArrayList<Ehealth>();

while(rs.next()) {

    Integer grasimi = rs.getInt("Total_grasimi");
    Integer carbohidrati = rs.getInt("Total_carbohidrati");                   
    Integer proteine = rs.getInt("Total_proteine");
    Integer calorii = rs.getInt("Total_calorii");

    Ehealth ehealthlist =
     new Ehealth(grasimi,carbohidrati,proteine,calorii);

    datalist.add(ehealthlist);
} 

// Sum the data 
int sum = 0;

for (Ehealth ehealth : datalist) {
    sum += ehealth.calorii;
}

// Print the total 
System.out.println(sum);
```